# AmE Equivalent for "people usually go to a cinema after going to a restaurant"

Tags: american-english, articles, north-american-english

I would like to write the equivalent of "people usually go to a cinema after going to a restaurant and they usually choose the closest cinema to the restaurant" in American English. I think the following could be the answer:

"people usually go to the movies after going to a restaurant and they usually choose the closest movie theater to the restaurant".

but I am not sure since the term "the movies" seems to refer to a known cinema not any cinema.

Comment: I would probably say "go to a movie" rather than "go to the movies".  And they "choose the theater that is closest to the restaurant."

Comment: Practically speaking, don't people choose the movie first, and then choose a restaurant near the theater where the movie is playing?

Comment: What @Mitch said.

Answer (score 4):

***The movies*** is not limited to a specific known cinema or set of cinemas, though it often refers to such when saying someting like “Let’s go to the movies tonight.”. Your recast of the sentence to use ***the movies*** and ***movie theater*** is fine.

Answer (score -1):

People usually go to dinner and a movie.